# Couldn't find "My work" in new Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Premium and couldn't find the section "My Work" in the Team Explorer to suspend my current work. My TFS is still on version 2010 ... does it have to be updated to see the "My Work" feature? Or how can I enable this section?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**My Work** is indeed a VS Premium feature. It does require TFS 2012 to activate, as it uses functionality that is new to the 2012 SDK.

On TFS 2012, you will have to settle on combining the **work items** and **pending changes** pages.

Comment: Did you mean `on TFS 2010` instead of `on TFS 2012`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to be connected to a TFS 2012 server in order to see the My Work page. Also, I believe that My Work is a VS Premium feature only.  You could test this by connecting your VS client to your account at tfspreview.com if you need a 2012 server to connect to.