# Why can't I view the MyWork pane in TFS plugin for VisualStudio 2012 when using Microsoft Git Provider?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

Since I installed the **Microsoft Git Provider** for full integration with my (Git controlled) projects hosted on **tfs.visualstudio.com**, the **My Work** pane on the **TFS Plugin for VS2012** (I'm using VS2012 Ultimate by the way) doesn't show up anymore.

But when I change the Source Control plugin on VS Options to: *None* or *Visual Studio Team Foundation Server* (which is not my source control provider), the **My Work** pane appears again.

Why can't I have access to this **My Work** pane (which gives much faster access to my Work Items instead of having to run Queries to see them) when using *Microsoft Git Provider*? It doesn't make sense to me, it's just a quick view of the WorkItems assigned to me, I thought this had nothing to do with my source control provider, it's just Work Items!

**Does anyone know why or how to fix this?** I don't want to have to run queries to open my current assigned tasks. The My Work pane is just perfect for quick access.

Comment: I have exactly same problem..

Comment: it seems that My Work is supported only in TFS 2012 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371374/couldnt-find-my-work-in-new-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "My Work" pane is not currently supported for connecting to projects hat have Git as the source control. This is due to things like "Shelving", which is fundamental to the features of My Work, not currently being available in Git. These are things that I would expect the product team to add in the future. I have no idea when it is likely to be available but "Shelving" is not currently available in Git in 2013 either.

I would expect these feature to be added on tfs.visualstudio.com before you see them on premise.