# TFS: Git vs Team Foudation Version Control

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I realised that when I choose Git as my source control when creating a new project in Team Foundation Service, I lose the following:

1) "My Work" menu in Team explorer

2) I can't track code modifications against a certain task in the product backlog assigned to a developer

It seems that Git is becoming very popular amongst developers as it is easier to create branches (from what I read), and this is something I'm very keen on, but being able to track code modifications against a task is equally, if not more important to me. Also, because "My Work" is no longer available, the option for a developer to submit code for review is also unavailable.

As I'm not that familiar with Git as a source control solution, can Git provide this level of granularity when it comes to down to wanting to review what code modifications have been made with respect to a particular task in the product back log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17958563/6309) mentions you don't have "My Work" because

> **This is due to things like "Shelving", which is fundamental to the features of My Work, not currently being available in Git**

Well... shelving is available in git, but not yet linked to TFS.

It is called [**stashing**: git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

But as seen in [this thread](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c/view/Discussions), the integration with Git is still not very tight, and **[tagging not yet fully supported](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4317925-add-tags-support-in-git-provider)**:

> I believe the problem that some of you are running into is **around untracked files in your repo**.
>   When you add a file to your repo and then include that add as a pending change in the VS tool, **we don't stage a change in the git repo until you commit** (at which point we both stage and commit the add).
>
> So, as an example scenario: you put a file, "`FileA.txt`" in Repo #1, add it, commit, and push the change up to your remote.
>   Now, in Repo #2, you add "`FileA.txt`" to your repo and include the change in VS but don't commit, then pull commits from your remote.
>   At this point you would have a conflict (because we're trying to pull down a file that exists untracked in your repo) that our tool doesn't support resolving through the UI.

That kind of last minute integration in git would make it hard to permform the same review directly in a git repo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know, or is there any word on whether this shelving feature will be integrated into TFS any time soon?

Comment: @The8thBit no, and I don't that as a suggestion for VS: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. Plus shelving change sets are a bit different of the shashes in git: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2794154-tfs-shelveset-to-be-a-personal-source-control

Comment: Would you say, that if this shelving thingy, and the ability to track code changes by task is really important, I should still stick with TFVC source control?