# MyWork Feature in Visual Studio Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have a question about a feature in Visual Studio Premium that can improve the quality of my work.

In Visual Studio 2012 Premium, there is a feature named "My Work". I work with Visual studio 2012 Ultimate, but there are just Work items and Pending Changes.

My question is: Can I integrate My Work in Visual Studio 2012, and how?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you connecting to? This only works with TFS 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 Premium or Ultimate. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12377024/736079

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couldn't find "My work" in new Visual Studio 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371374/couldnt-find-my-work-in-new-visual-studio-2012)